# What could possibly explain this weird Log.v() behavior?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

In a very short and simple LVL callback function, I have:

```
public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {
  Log.v(getMethodName(2), "TID: " + android.os.Process.myTid());
  Log.v("applicationError()", "TID: " + android.os.Process.myTid());
  if (!isFinishing()) { // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
    String result = String.format(getString(R.string.application_error), errorCode);
    displayResult(result);
  }
```

this callback is a method member of

```
 private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback
```

and the getMethodName() defined as the application's activity method:

```
 public static String getMethodName(final int depth)
  {
    final StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    String retStr = ste[depth+1].getClassName() + "." + ste[depth+1].getMethodName();

    if (retStr == null)
      retStr = "This is weird.";
    else if (retStr.length() < 1)
      retStr = "This is even weirder.";

    return retStr;
  }
```

Now, the weird part:

**LogCat *always* displays the 2nd `Log.v()` but *never* displays the 1st `Log.v()`!**

At first, I thought that perhaps retStr is either null or empty, but the logs clearly don't show anything like that.

In other methods calling `Log.v(getMethodName(2), "TID: " + android.os.Process.myTid());` everything works fine.

What could possibly explain this weird and inconsistent `Log.v()` behavior?

**UPDATE:** I implemented the 1st part in CheGuaVerra's answer and this is the interesting log I got:

```
06-16 01:02:57.080: INFO/First(835): Log.v
06-16 01:02:57.080: INFO/First(835): [ 06-16 01:02:57.080   835:0x34b V/com.example.baseapp.googlepaid.MyActivityGooglePaid$MyLicenseCheckerCallback.applTID: 843
06-16 01:02:57.080: INFO/Second(835): Log.v
06-16 01:02:57.080: VERBOSE/applicationError()(835): TID: 843
```

**UPDATE 2:** I implemented the both parts in CheGuaVerra's answer and this is the interesting log I got:

```
06-16 10:13:22.588: INFO/First(1122): Log.v
06-16 10:13:22.588: INFO/getMethodName(1122): Start
06-16 10:13:22.588: INFO/getMethodName(1122): [ 06-16 10:13:22.588  1122:0x46a V/com.example.baseapp.googlepaid.MyActivityGooglePaid$MyLicenseCheckerCallback.applTID: 1130
06-16 10:13:22.588: INFO/Second(1122): Log.v
06-16 10:13:22.588: VERBOSE/applicationError()(1122): TID: 1130
```

Is it possible that `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[depth+1].getMethodName()` simply doesn't "like" being called from the UI thread?

Also, it seems that `Log.v()` doesn't like weird strings like `[ 06-16 10:13:22.588  1122:0x46a V/com.example.baseapp.googlepaid.MyActivityGooglePaid$MyLicenseCheckerCallback.appl`.

Comment: Nothing. Something else is wrong, you must be missing something.

Comment: Figure out how to reproduce it and debug it.

Comment: @Chris It's consistently reproducible. How to debug it?

Comment: That's a whole other SO question entirely.

Comment: @Chris I know how to debug in general. But this particular problem is much harder. I think it has to do with stack corruption and/or the fact that `Log.v()` is called from a callback that runs on a **different thread**.

Comment: Whew, I didn't want to get into how to debug.. Does the debugger stop if you set a breakpoint at the missing call to Log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to do something like this to trace it out?

```
public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {     
  Log.i("First", "Log.v");

  Log.v(getMethodName(2), "TID: " + android.os.Process.myTid());

  Log.i("Second", "Log.v");

  Log.v("applicationError()", "TID: " + android.os.Process.myTid());

  if (!isFinishing()) { // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
    String result = String.format(getString(R.string.application_error), errorCode);

  displayResult(result);
}


 public static String getMethodName(final int depth)
  {
    Log.i("getMethodName", "Start");
    final StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    String retStr = ste[depth+1].getClassName() + "." + ste[depth+1].getMethodName();

    if (retStr == null)
      retStr = "This is weird.";
    else if (retStr.length() < 1)
      retStr = "This is even weirder.";

    Log.i("getMethodeName", retStr);

    return retStr;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks + 1 for your answer. See the result of the  implementation of your suggestion above.

Comment: @aN00b The next step I think is to do a Proof of concept with simple classes and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Also add a try catch block in the getMethodName function, might help

Comment: I haven't been able to come across the problem again. So accepting for now. Thanks.